# What to teach in a class about the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I'm going to give a lecture in a public contest (like a civil service examination to be a university public teacher in my country) about the intermediate value theorem in 45 minutes. I'm going to give this lecture to three professors (the examiners) but it's *like* I'm going to give it to undergraduate students.

Since the proof of the intermediate value theorem is too hard to show to someone who's never learned real analysis, what should I do in this class? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: just use visuals

Comment: @suomynonA what do you mean? and after that?

Comment: migrating your question to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ does make sense.

Comment: @user42912 Well when I learned it the instructor used images you can use images like searching on google gives some pretty good results

Answer (score 3):

You should first start with some explanation of the theorem via graphic illustration and then present some key applications. Apart from those mentioned in the other answer one of the basic applications of intermediate value theorem is the existence of $n$'th roots of positive real numbers. Usually when roots are introduced in high school no one really discusses their existence.

Maybe you can also add some historical remarks about the theorem and the fact that the theorem was used much before it was finally proved. And in fact people did not even think it needed a proof.

And then you can provide proofs based on multiple approaches. It is also important to stress that intermediate value property is not the privilege of continuous functions only and there are discontinuous functions which have this property and one important class of such functions is the class of derivatives.

---

**Note**: I am not an educator by profession and the above is not based on any teaching experience but rather based on what I would have liked in a class on this theorem if I were a student.

Comment: Regarding your comment about derivatives satisfying the intermediate value property, I'd avoid bringing this up because it's almost certainly not meaningful for the intended audience. However, the example $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$ could be used to give a nice visual example of a discontinuous example.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Well, I meant this could be just mentioned and not discussed in detail. Or perhaps it can also be avoided if it does not fit in 45 min lecture. But yes I think you have experience as an educator and your advice is more meaningful.

Comment: FYI, here are two concerns I have with talking about derivatives having this property (and this despite how much I've posted about it over the years): (1) the intended audience might not have studied derivatives at all (a chapter or two on limits and continuity often precede introducing the derivative); (2) before an upper level real analysis course, students are rarely if ever told or shown that derivatives can be discontinuous, so saying derivatives have the intermediate value property will probably seem like a special case of this result for continuous functions.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : Fully agree with your points.

Answer (score 2):

You should mention some of its consequences, such as:

- every polynomial function from $\mathbb R$ into itself with odd degree has at least one root;
- if $a,b\in\mathbb R$ are such that $a^2+b^2=1$ then there is some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$.

Comment: I've never seem the second one, really interesting. Can you remember more nice applications like these ones?

Comment: @user42912 You can use it to prove to certain equations have solutions. Take $x=\cos x$, for instance. Another application: during a round-trip, there is some point, other than the starting point, in which you will be exactly as high as where you started.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce the problem by stating a real world example, e.g.

> This morning we had a temperatur of $10$ °C, and now its $15$ °C. So we conclude that there must have been a time between this morning and now where we had a temperature of $13$ °C.

But why can we conclude this? This is not a universal rule, e.g.

> Yesterday my bank account contained $100\$$. Then I went to the bank and cashed out $50\$$, i.e. now I have $50\$$ left on my account. Was there a time between yesterday and now where my account had exactly $70\$$ on it?

No. Here you can conclude that the important property we need to derive such kind of intermediate statements is *continuity*.

Now you can go about to give a short definition of what continuity means (if necessary) and a general formulation of the intermediate value theorem (IVT). A full proof might be to hard (as you said), but I think that the core idea of repeated bisection can be explained pretty nicely with images. Point out where continuity is used.

Demonstrate that the IVT is *very* important because it is used to prove some very obvious results which are still not trivial to show without it, e.g.

- If you have a (convex) shape and a curve starting on the inside and ending on the outside of this shape, then this curve must have crossed the shapes boundary somewhere.

Or some more surprising results like

- There are two points on exactly opposite sides of the earth which have the exact same temperature and air pressure at the same time.

The proofs might be somehow hand wavy and not completely rigorous (especially in the last example), but you can give an idea on how to apply the theorem.

You can mention that the IVT is a very nice tool to show the existence of results without computing them, i.e. it is a (seemingly) non-constructive tool. It can be used to show that certain solutions or intersection points exist but do not bother with computing them if you are not interested in the exact value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make the proof accessible to a large audience, by explaining technicalities in layman's terms. Most of the required concepts are intuitive. Show how intuition can be formalized.